# Trouble in differentiating the Comma operator vs comma separator

Tags: c++, c++11, comma-operator

I am having trouble differentiating comma as operator or separator. Have gone through various questions but none explains when the comma acts a operator vs when it acts as separator. The answers just say here it acts as operator and there it acts as separator.
My question is HOW CAN I SAY LOOKING AT A STATEMENT that when comma is a operator and when is it a separator.
Historically i understand that operator needs operands and comma is usually a separator. But how it transforms into operator is confusing me.

```
int a;
a = 1, 2, 3;
printf("%d", a);

int a = 1, 2, 3;
printf("%d", a);
```

Comment: When you look at this code does it make sense to be assigning 3 values to 1 int variable?

Comment: @RetiredNinja - it doesn't but that's not my question. My question is about the ability to distinguish comma as operator from comma as separator. The second assignment is erroneous but still there are possibilities where comma can act as an operator. I am unable to look at a code and then point out that comma is operator or a separator.

Comment: You just need to learn to recognize different uses. In my experience the comma operator is rarely used and it is completely obvious when it is used. I'm not sure how anyone could answer this question.

Comment: @RetiredNinja - you say comma is used as operator and it's obvious when it's used. Why don't you share an example where comma is an operator vs comma as separator? I am attempting to learn only.

Comment: I don't think there is a shortcut; you need to understand the grammar of C++. Comma is a separator in those places where the grammar of the language expects a list of declarators, initializers, enumerators, parameters, arguments, etc. Comma is an operator only in those places where the grammar expects an **expression**.

Comment: Probably RetiredNinja _could_ give you examples, but you seem to not want examples. You say you saw many answer that show examples, but you want to know _'how you can say looking at the statement'_ which case it is. That means not another example, but rather a method to recognize which one the example is.

Comment: @CiaPan - if you see my answer I have asked retiredninja to share examples.

Comment: You are hitting upon one of my pet peeves with C++ (and it's ancestor C):  the contextual meaning of a token (*keyword* or *punctuation*) that varies based on context.  It's not something that will ever be fixed, so I don't harp on it.  Just part of the learning cliff.

Comment: @Eljay Possibly brackets `( )` and `{ }` have even more different context-dependent meanings than a comma...

Answer (score 2):

In contexts where you can have a comma seperator, it is used.  When you can't, it is the comma operator.

The comma seperator applies to:

1. Various kinds of initialization (these occur inside `()` or `{}`, but not all such brackets are initialization).

   ```
   struct Bob {
     int x,y;
     Bob(int,int);
   };
   Bob b1{1,2};
   Bob b2 = Bob{1,2};
   Bob b3 = Bob(1,2);
   ```
2. Declaring multiple variables

   ```
   int x =0, y =2;
   ```
3. `[]` captures of lambdas.

   ```
   int x = 2, y = 0;
   std::cout << [x, y]() mutable { return x+y; }();
   ```
4. Function/method call arguments and parameter lists.

   ```
   void foo(int, int); // parameter list
   foo(1,2); // arguments
   ```
5. Template arguments and parameter lists.

   ```
   template<class T, class U>
   T convert(U u){ return T( std::forward<U>(u) ); }
   auto d = convert<double, int>(3);
   ```
6. A list of enumeration enumerators

   ```
   enum class Bird {
     Chicken,
     Raven,
     Roc,
   };
   ```

... I probably missed something.

Otherwise it is either a syntax error, or an expression, and the `,` is treated as the comma operator.  One gotcha is that `operator[]` does not take a parameter list, so `vec[1,2]` has a `,` operator in it.  Do not rely on this, I have seen what appears to be serious intent by the standards committee to deprecate it and (maybe eventually) allow multi-argument `[]`.

```
int a;
a = 1, 2, 3;
```

comma operator.  `a` is `1`, and `2` and `3` are discarded.

```
printf("%d", a);
```

comma separator.

```
int a = 1, 2, 3;
```

invalid code.

```
printf("%d", a);
```

comma separator.

Comment: `()` can be used for both - with `FooClass(int,int)` both `FooClass(1,2)` and `FooClass((3,1),2)` execute same calls.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - so in the code I shared  can I say that comma is trying to act as operator in both cases? As per your explanation , I think no where in my code examples, comma is acting as a separator? Please confirm.

Comment: @quimby - so in FooClass(1,2) can i say comma is acting as separator? And in my code examples also?

Comment: @Test Your code examples in the OPO contain both comma as an operator and a separator.  I assume `FooClass` is the name of a class; then yes, `FooClass(1,2)` is a case where `,` is a separator.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - can you elaborate a bit as how comma is acting both as operator and separator in my original code example in question?

Comment: @Test Yes, in my first example it is separator in my second example the first comma is operator, second separator. In you second example the commas want to act as separators but it is not allowed.